# NSTableView with NSProgressIndicator in its cells as custom views

Tags: macos, autolayout, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to write a file uploading app on mac fro which i need to show upload progress for each file so i created a NSTableView and put a custom NSTableCellView in it which has NSProgressIndicator in it but for some reasons the progress bar is showing on top of the header. Can anyone tell why? and i would really appreciate if anyone can tell how to make it go behind the header like the rest of the data. Please refer the attached image for details.

And i would like to ask one more thing is there any way to specify automatic height of the cells like UITableViewAutomaticDimension with auto layout in iOS all i could find is to provide hard coded height for the cells to NSTableView

[image: Screenshot of app i am trying to create]

Comment: I am reviving dead posts here, but I did notice making the NSScrollView layer-backed (`[sv setWantsLayer:YES]`) fixes the issue. I got that idea [here](http://jwilling.com/blog/optimized-nstableview-scrolling/) on an unrelated issue, and I thus don't understand what happened here...